# Not able to extract values from raster TIFF in EPSG:26912, but can in EPSG:4326?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, geopandas, rasterio, data-frame

I have an elevation file (.tif) in EPSG:4326 and point data for wildfire occurrence in the same projection. When I use this projection, I can use the following code to extract the elevation value, for the corresponding point and add that into the dataframe:

```
wfdf=gpd.read_file('wildfire_all_1980_2016_gdb/wf_all_1980_2016_clip.shp')
elev=rasterio.open('elevation/elevhillshade.tif')

fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(12,12))
wfdf.plot(ax=ax, color='orangered', alpha=0.5)
show(elev, ax=ax)

coords = [(x,y) for x, y in zip(wfdf.DLONGITUDE, wfdf.DLATITUDE)] 
wfdf['Elevation'] = [x[0] for x in elev.sample(coords)]
wfdf
```

However, I need this in EPSG:26912 to be more accurately represented. I have tried to reproject both layers into EPSG:26912, but then the elevation values just result in my default NoData value -9999 for every point. So I then created a whole new raster for elevation, already in the correct projection, using mosaic tool in ArcGIS. I checked in the software, and there were no NoData values, the raster is all good. However, same thing happens - I read it in, I reproject the wfdf fire occurrence point data to EPSG:26912 as so:

```
wfdf=wfdf.to_crs(epsg=26912)
```

I run the same code, and again, all values for Elevation are -9999. It only seems to read data values in the EPSG:4326 and I cannot find a solution online.

If I run the Extract Values to Points in ArcGIS for the correct coordinate system, it works also, so it's something happening in Python.